# Tracing Problems With Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, image-trace

I've created a logo using Fireworks and I'm trying to vectorise it in Inkscape.  The problem that I have is that my whole logo has a solid black glow around it to make it really stand out but when I trace it in Inkscape it always leaves a white outline around the whole thing - How do I trace an object without it doing this?

Comment: I think it is better to put the image and working to give better answer...

Answer (score 2):

With Inkscape we can not trace object effects such as glow, drop shadow, stroke properties, gradients, or similar.

If we trace an image with any such effects a fake gradient or glow is simulated on tracing by adding a plethora of objects for each color gradient. This will dramatically increase your SVG's file size, and it will not be rendered with smooth gradients as colors are limited to a maximum of 256.

It is the object's geometry, and optionally it's solid color only that can be traced to a vector graphic. Even all strokes will be traced to separate objects.

If we plan to apply effects to our objects then we will have to create them plain, i.e. without effects, first to add any effects to the created vector objects later. Then it may be easier to create them in Inkscape in the fist place

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Takkat - I can't really explain it but I did find out what the problem was ( Basically the white line was bits of the other layers overlapping ) and edited my PNG's so that they could be traced individually and put back together in Inkscape.  I'm not really a graphic designer but I made this logo in Fireworks & it looked great for my website so thought I'd give it a go as a vector - It's far from perfect but it looks fine to me.

Comment: @FootPromoter: great you got it solved :)